# aplay: main:831: audio open error: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, manjaro

When I run this code:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("Hello, World!")
engine.runAndWait()
```

It shows:

```
aplay: main:831: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

I have `pyttsx3==2.90` installed on my system(Manjaro 21.1.2 Pahvo).

I have tried reinstalling pip and pyttsx3 too, and I also checked the syntax several times and everything seems fine.

Any suggestions will help a lot :)

Comment: That doesn't seem to be due to python directly, but linked with ALSA. Try running `aplay` with a sound file to see if that works. If not, you could try reinstalling the `alsa-utils` package.

Comment: @Hacked I reinstalled `alsa-utils` but it still doesn't works :(

Comment: then your problem might lie in the drivers and firmware. try (re)installing or updating `alsa-firmware`, `sof-firmware`, `alsa-ucm-conf`, as well as your audio drivers (btw, all the tips I'm giving you come from the Arch Wiki, you should really give it a look)

Comment: I have the same issue on WSL :(

Comment: I have had the same issue for several years for the ROOT user in XUBUNTU. Regular users work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding those lines to my script:

```
  os.system('sudo apt install -y espeak')
  os.system('sudo apt-get -y update')
  os.system('sudo apt-get install -y alsa-utils')
  os.system('sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common')
  os.system('sudo apt-get install -y ffmpeg')
```

Alternatively you can run those commands in your terminal as well. Had no more issues after that.